# How to add pagination to navigate blog post pages (Node/Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am building a blog site and trying to use pagination to navigate the pages of blog posts when there are more than 3 posts stored in the database. I'm trying to pass data from the front-end when clicking "newer" or "previous" buttons to the back-end to control the pages. How can I go about doing that?

I feel like I have to use the POST method somehow.

Here is my front-end code in EJS. These are the buttons that control the pages of posts.

```
  <% if(totalItems > 3){ %>
  <div class="page-buttons">
    <form action="/">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info newer-posts">Next</button>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info older-posts">Previous</button>
    </form>

  </div>
  <% } %>
```

Here is the route on the back-end.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let currentPage = req.query.page || 1;
  let perPage = 3;
  let totalItems;

  Post.find()
    .countDocuments()
    .then(count => {
      totalItems = count;
      Post.find()
        .skip((currentPage - 1) * perPage)
        .limit(perPage)
        .then(posts => {
            res.render("home", {
              posts: posts,
              totalItems: totalItems
            });
        });
    })
});
```

I expect clicking the buttons will increment or decrement the `currentPage` variable and render the proper pages of blog posts from the back-end. But instead, it does nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the total amount of items (blog posts), you can do some simple math to know what the last page would be.

```
const lastPage = Math.ceil(totalItems / perPage);
```

Just like you're passing `posts` and `totalItems`, I would also pass `currentPage` and `lastPage`. We could essentially do the above math in the template, but why would we?

```
res.render("home", {
    posts,
    currentPage,
    totalItems,
    lastPage
});
// The above notation is shorthand for prop: value
```

Now, in the template, we can decide whether to show the previous and next page button based on the variables we passed.

If `currentPage` is higher than 1, we must be on the second page or beyond, so show a link to the current page `?page=<%= currentPage - 1 %>`.

If `currentPage` is lower than `lastPage`, we have not reached the end yet, so we show the link to the next page. Which would be `?page=<%= currentPage + 1 %>`

There is no need to use a form here. Simple `<a>` tags will suffice.